# Issue in PDFBox

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox

```
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.0'
```

This is my kotlin code:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = data?.data

            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri!!, "r", null)
            val file = File(cacheDir, contentResolver.getFileName(uri))
            if (file.exists()) {
                Loader.loadFDF(file)
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am facing this error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.documnet.translator, PID: 31595
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:796 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.documnet.translator/com.example.documnet.translator.DashboardActivity}: java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5946)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5985)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.FDFParser.parse(FDFParser.java:98)
at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadFDF(Loader.java:79)
at com.example.documnet.translator.DashboardActivity.onActivityResult(DashboardActivity.kt:221)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5939)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5985) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

Comment: Is your file a .FDF file? Have you verified that it isn't empty or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your stack trace says it all:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.FDFParser.parse(FDFParser.java:98)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.Loader.loadFDF(Loader.java:79)
 at com.example.documnet.translator.DashboardActivity.onActivityResult(DashboardActivity.kt:221)
```

Thus, the file you attempt to load here:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    Loader.loadFDF(file)
}
```

does not appear to be a valid FDF file.

---

In a comment you protest

> It's pdf.

Please look again at the method you call: `Loader.loadFDF`. FDFs and PDFs are different (albeit related) file formats.

Thus, if you want to load a PDF, use a `Loader.loadPDF` overload instead.

Comment: I have logged my file extension.

```
2024-03-12 15:59:47.725 12599-12599 logKey                  
com.example.documnet.translator      D  File extension pdf
```
It's pdf.

Comment: @Affan *"It's pdf"* - Then why do you try to load it as a fdf?

Comment: When I use LoadPDF() then it there is an other problem.  Didn't find class "java.awt.Point" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7aGiJpUWm6X4ShR67FRl7g==/com.example.documnet.translator-L1vhitVANVlA9Pwvn8TGqw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7aGiJpUWm6X4ShR67FRl7g==/com.example.documnet.translator-L1vhitVANVlA9Pwvn8TGqw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~7aGiJpUWm6X4ShR67FRl7g==/com.example.documnet.translator-L1vhitVANVlA9Pwvn8TGqw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

Comment: Error:  Didn't find class "java.awt.Point".

Comment: That's a different issue. Pdfbox requires awt classes which are packed in regular Java libraries but not on Android. But there are some external libraries you can add that provide some of the awt classes on Android, too. I don't know them exactly and I don't know whether they suffice for pdfbox

Comment: Use https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android for an Android version of PDFBox that works around the java.awt.Point issue